# Migrating Service Fabric app to Kubernetes

Tags: azure, docker, kubernetes, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateless

Having a simple SF application (API + Service projects), how would one convert it so it runs on Kubernetes?

- Can anyone please explain if it's possible to containerize SF app and deploy it to Minikube/Kubernetes?
- Or does it have to be re-written in some specific way?

Trying to migrate from SF to Kubernetes.
Any insight greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you cannot do that if you are using SF specific primitives (like actors), because kubernetes does not provide those. I dont think you can easily rewrite those, tbh. That would be anything but straight forward.

If you are not, however, its just a matter of containerizing all of the apps and deploying them to kubernetes like you normally would.

Comment: are saying these apps would have to be re-written and any references to Service Fabric would have to be removed? What would one use to replace Actors?

Comment: obviously, kubernetes cannot provide you with SF actors.

Comment: @ShaneKm if you're smitten with the actor pattern, Akka.NET supports clustering and remoting and implements the actor pattern.  A quick googling shows me several examples of implementing this in a Kubernetes environment.  Check it out!  Other than that, all other Service Fabric references must also be removed.  Any service-to-service communication must be refactored to use http instead of Service Fabric Remoting.   Also, any Stateful services must be refactored.  All SF Native or command line services must be containerized.